# Android Studio - Show Information From Main Activity in Overlay Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service

So here is the problem, I am trying to make an overlay that shows data from the main app, the app is running with no errors but it is not actually showing the data.

Main.java : This is the main app, where all the data entry and other stuff happens.

```
package com.schnetzapps.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    Switch toggleOverlaySwitch;
    TextView overlayLabel;
    EditText testText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
        overlayLabel = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.overlayLabel);
        toggleOverlaySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.openOverlay);

        toggleOverlaySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                toggleService();
                testText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testText);
                overlayLabel.setText(testText.getText());
                testText.setText(overlayLabel.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    private void toggleService(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverlayService.class);
        if(!stopService(intent)){
            startService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Overlay.java : This is an overlay designed to show the user information as it changes no matter what other apps may be open.
        package com.schnetzapps.myapplication;

```
        import android.app.Service;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
        import android.os.IBinder;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.WindowManager;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Overlay extends Service {

    LinearLayout oView;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        oView = new LinearLayout(this);
        int col =  Color.parseColor("#4286f4");
        oView.setBackgroundColor(col);
        int width = 500;
        int height = 500;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(width, height, x, y,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.overlay, null);
        oView.addView(layout);
        wm.addView(oView, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(oView!=null){
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.removeView(oView);
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml : This is the design of the Main app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Switch
        android:text="Open Overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/openOverlay" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Test"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/testText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

overlay.xml : this is the overlay design with the label that I am trying to set the text of.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/overlayLayout" >
        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/overlayLabel" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am not getting any null reference exceptions stating that I am pointing to the wrong TextView, and the overlay is toggling nicely as required, why is the text on the overlay not changing to what has been entered into the EditText field?

Screenshots
The overlay is not toggled to be on, so the overlay is not visible:
[image]

The overlay has been toggled on, but the TextView is not showing the text from the EditText:
[image]

I am sure i'm missing something stupid... any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling around, I discovered that the solution is of course the Intent system: `intent.putExtra(key, value);`  and  `intent.getStringExtra(key);`

In my code above I changed the following code:

```
private void toggleService(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverlayService.class);
    if(!stopService(intent)){
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

To include the Intent putter:

```
private void toggleService(String key, String value){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverlayService.class);
    intent.putExtra(key, value);
    if(!stopService(intent)){
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

And in the Overlay Service, I change most of the code so it now looks like this:

```
package com.schnetzapps.myapplication;

        import android.app.Service;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
        import android.os.IBinder;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.WindowManager;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;
        import android.widget.TextView;

public class OverlayService extends Service {
    String data;
    LinearLayout oView;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        data = intent.getStringExtra("testText");
        RunOverlay();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    void RunOverlay () {
        oView = new LinearLayout(this);
        int col =  Color.parseColor("#4286f4");
        oView.setBackgroundColor(col);
        int width = 500;
        int height = 500;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(width, height, x, y,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.overlay, null);

        oView.addView(layout);
        TextView t = (TextView)oView.findViewById(R.id.overlayLabel);
        t.setText(data);
        wm.addView(oView, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(oView!=null){
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.removeView(oView);
        }
    }
}
```

The result of course is that when the toggle is changed, the overlay window will show the text from the EditText field.

[image]